# Can I get rid of the "Take your Lightroom everywhere" screen?

Tags: lightroom-catalog, lightroom-6

Since Lightroom 6, whenever I create a new catalog, Lightroom asks me if I want to "synchronise" with a screen saying "Take your Lightroom everywhere".

How can I prevent that screen from appearing every time I create a new catalog?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac? Or are you using the Lightroom App on IOS or Android?

Comment: On Windows. I am not using any Lightroom mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

When creating Collections, in the Create Collection dialog, deselect the Sync With Lightroom Mobile checkbox.

Or

In an existing collection, go to space just above navigator where your name is located. In the drop menu, select the pause symbol for Lightroom Mobile Sync.

Comment: I don't see any of those. I do not use collections, only catalogs. Also I don't see any place with my name. An there is no "Sync with Lightroom Mobile" in the Create Collection dialog.